# How to collapse multiple unique observations into one and find a mean?

Tags: dataframe

Data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2yef22u96dd3s5/female_mentions_centrality_1.xlsx?dl=0

Data set screenshot:
[image]

I have a data set which looks like the picture above. It has multiple (unique) observations for the same Movie Name. For example, there are 3 unique observations for the movie Aan Milo Sajna and 2 for Aap Ke Saath.

I want that wherever there are multiple observations for a given Movie Name, they get collapsed into a single observation such that each variable value is the mean of the multiple observations.

For example, see below.

Transformed data set screenshot:
[image]

The Movie Names that had single observations remain untouched. But the three observations for Aan Milo Sajna and the 2 observations for Aap Ke Sath get collapsed into single observations. And each of the variable values is changed to the mean of the multiple observations as shown in the picture.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: please post the data, not an image.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the data set: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2yef22u96dd3s5/female_mentions_centrality_1.xlsx?dl=0>

Answer (score 0):

```
df_mean = df.groupby('MOVIE NAME').agg(np.mean).reset_index()

                    MOVIE NAME   FEMALE MENTIONS  TOTAL FEMALE CENTRALITY   FEMALE COUNT   AVERAGE FEMALE CENTRALITY
0                         1920            19.000                  258.417        140.500                       1.669
1                     100 Days            18.600                  435.320        153.000                       3.427
2                          13B             2.333                   74.289         23.333                       1.259
3                  1920 London            14.500                  926.183        152.500                       3.118
4           1942: A Love Story            11.000                  398.500         78.000                       5.109
...                        ...               ...                      ...            ...                         ...
2029                   Zindagi             5.000                  119.667         45.667                       2.506
2030  Zindagi Na Milegi Dobara            13.000                  265.750        135.000                       1.865
2031         Zindagi Tere Naam             2.500                   57.500         21.250                       3.689
2032                  Zubeidaa             0.000                 1260.122        101.000                      14.421
2033                     Zulmi             1.000                    5.333          4.000                       1.333
```